# "Rendering" polygons that are transparent OpenGL

Tags: opengl, render, polygon

I am developing an engine and the way I am handling boundaries the player is not supposed to reach is to have actual polygons as these boundaries. Now, I am wondering how to "render" the polgon but have it non visible.

My main question is: does OpenGL have a way to do this natively?

If not, what if I was to create a texture the way I usually load in the texture but have this texture simply be a single pixel. I could set the alpha channel to that specific pixel color and then use an alpha mask as I do normally with masked textures.

Any advice?

Comment: "Now, I am wondering how to "render" the polgon but have it non visible." How do you render something that's not visible; what's the point? Why does what you render affect where the player can and cannot go? It sounds like your engine is very confused; what is drawn should not affect behavior (where things can go).

Comment: @Nico Bolas I use my BSP tree to calculate collision. Collision effects the entire polygon. Now that i think about it, I could still calculate collision without rendering the polygon. Correct?

Comment: Exactly. Your BSP polygons don't have to match what you actually render.

Comment: @Nico Bolas Thank you. I am going to go ahead and check out the tutorials in your profile. Looks like a good way to learn.

Answer (score 2):

> My main question is: does OpenGL have a way to do this natively?

No!

OpenGL only draws nicely colored triangles, lines and point to a framebuffer, and that's it.

- It is not a scene graph.
- It is not a geometry library.
- It is not a collision detection framework.

Answer (score 0):

The question comments solved the problem you are having **but** there's a way to do what you actually asked so I'm putting it here anyway.

The question as I understood it is about rendering something in the depth buffer (and maybe stencil) but nowhere else. To achieve this, you simply have to use [glColorMask](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glColorMask.xml) like so before drawing the transparent polygons:

```
glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
```

and restore the color mask afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render the boundaries as transparent polygons - you could use the blending method as given here : http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm

Is that what you were looking for ?